# Regular Expression to extract path + filename from URL

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract 'vets/gth/summary.htm' from 'http://www.abc.gh.gov/vets/gth/summary.htm' by using the following regular expression: ^http:\/\/www.abc.gh.gov

I get the following output: 'ets/gth/summary.htm'  I do not get the 'v' in the vets.

If I change the url to 'http://www.abc.gh.gov/**rets/gth/summary.htm**' it works fine. The regex does not work when the first letter after 'http://www.abc.gh.gov/' is one of the following 'httpwwwabcghov'. Notice that these letters are present in 'http://www.abc.gh.gov/'.

Please advice.

Comment: What do you mean extract?  Regex is a matching language, what are you using to get the other part?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to `^(http:\/\/www.abc.gh.gov)` to force the whole block, nothing less and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a `/` to the end of the regex (escaped of course) `\/` so you can just search for the slash?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, I don't know what you mean by "output" since the normal output of a regular expression execution is the part that **matched** your expression, not the part that didn't.

However, I would recommend the following approach:

1. Find the index of the third `/`
2. Substring from `index + 1` to the end.